# How to check if an icon element is visible?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a site wherein it shows a warning icon every time it detects something wrong with the site's content.

[image]

This icon's tag is always present in the background, but the icon itself only becomes visible whenever the tag has the **::before**.

[image]

Now what I need to do is to verify if the tag is populated so I can make sure that I catch the icon every time it is present.

The code I have right now always detects the icon because it only catches the tag itself, not its content.

Please show me a better way to do this, thank you in advance!

```
if(driver.FindElement(By.Id("alertmsgBtn")) != null)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Warning Alert Present");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No Warning");
            }
```

Comment: What if you use visibility of web element?

Comment: Yeah I was trying to use this ElementIsVisible(), but I'm not sure if it's still supported or not since I don't really see recent sample codes, that's why I posted here.

Comment: Could you add html content of <i>, when icon is not visible?

Comment: can you please share the html of the element when it's not present(displayed) on the page. Have you checked with `driver.FindElement(By.Id("alertmsgBtn")).is_displayed()`?

Comment: @supputuri Thanks for this, it actually just needed a little change. changed it to .Displayed

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, then the following code should work for you:

```
            if (driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#alertmsgBtn icon")) != null)
            {            
                Console.WriteLine("Warning Alert Present");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No Warning");
            }
```

Where we are searching for element with id *alertmsgBtn* and element *icon* inside it.
If there is another element when icon is visible, then you can simply replace name of that element with ***icon*** in my example.

Answer (score 0):

If it uses `aria-hidden="true"` to hide the icon when there is no warning then you can use `GetAttribute("aria-hidden")` to check if its value is true or false to make your decisions.

```
String IsHidden = driver.FindElement(By.Id("alertmsgBtn")).GetAttribute("aria-hidden");
if( IsHidden == "true" ) {
   Console.WriteLine("No Warning");
} else {
   Console.WriteLine("Warning Alert Present");
}
```

Comment: it only appears when that ::before is present